# How to get width of scrollable area in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have a panel (Ext.Panel) with autoScroll = true. How to get the width of hidden area or get coordinates of point at panel in terms of scrollable space? For example, panel scrolled to the right. I need solution for ExtJs 3.4, but answers for ExtJs 4 will be interesting too.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a panel, the body is the scrolled element, so you'd need:

`panel.body.dom.scrollWidth;`